# ORA-00936 on query

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00936

I am facing issue ORA-00936 using the bellow query, I believe is because of the select inside of sleect using the start_time_as, but have no clue on how to solve.

```sql
SELECT
        YEAR,
        MONTH,
        CAST (count(*) AS INT) AS JobNbr
FROM
        (
        SELECT
                To_Char( To_Date( '01.01.1970 06:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:Mi:Ss') + STARTIME / 86400,'YYYY-MM-DD') as start_time_as,
                UNIQUE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_time_as) AS YEAR,
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_time_as) AS MONTH,
                EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_time_as) AS DAY,
                JOID,
                STARTIME,
                STATUS
        FROM
                AEDBADMIN.UJO_JOB_RUNS
        WHERE
                STATUS = '5' ) AS derivedTable
GROUP BY
        YEAR,
        MONTH
```

The bellow query works great, bellow is the query with the results.

[image: img1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the `AS` keyword for your `derivedTable`. `AS` is used for columns (optionally) not for tables.

Second, you are defining `start_time_as` in the same query block you are using it in. You will have to wait until the outer parent query block to use that reference. Nest one level deeper so you can do those `EXTRACT` operations on an already-defined `start_time_as` column.

Thirdly, you can only use `DISTINCT`/`UNIQUE` at the start of a column list, not after your first column.

Lastly, you can't `TO_CHAR` your date formula and then use it with `EXTRACT`. Leave it as a date:

Also, though it works, there is no need to cast the `count(*)` as an integer. It already is.

```
SELECT
        YEAR,
        MONTH,
        count(*) AS JobNbr
FROM
        (
        SELECT UNIQUE
               EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_time_as) AS YEAR,
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_time_as) AS MONTH,
                EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_time_as) AS DAY,
                JOID,
                STARTIME,
                STATUS
           FROM (SELECT joid,
                        startime,
                        status,
                        To_Date( '01.01.1970 06:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:Mi:Ss') + STARTIME / 86400 as start_time_as
                   FROM AEDBADMIN.UJO_JOB_RUNS
                  WHERE STATUS = '5' )) derivedTable
GROUP BY
        YEAR,
        MONTH
```

Comment: same error, I believe the issue is around the To_Char function I am using to have the start_time_as then to extract the year,month and day.  Any hints on how I can define start_time_as to use it ?

Comment: @JuscelinoCandidodeLimaJuni,  Please see my answer again, I was in the middle of adding additional problems when you commented.

Comment: Amazing, it worked like a charm!! thanks for the fast response!

Comment: @JuscelinoCandidodeLimaJuni consider marking the question as answered. That is the best way to say thanks on SO.